# In my nodejs user auth, taken from boilerplate, my registration works but not my login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express-session

I am making a fairly simple session-based user auth for a nodejs project for school based on a boilerplate from an online tutorial that can be found [here](https://www.codementor.io/emjay/how-to-build-a-simple-session-based-authentication-system-with-nodejs-from-scratch-6vn67mcy3). Simple change over to mysql instead of prestege using mysql and mysql2 node packages.

Everything works EXPECT that the login function does not seem to create a persistant session. You can register as a new user and it will take you to the dashboard section of the website, but logging in will not. Logging in will console log to gitbash, however, that the user is being authenticated.

```
                 //server.js
                    var express = require('express');
                    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
                    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
                    var session = require('express-session');
                    var morgan = require('morgan');
                    var User = require('./models/user');

                    // invoke an instance of express application.
                    var app = express();

                    // set our application port
                    app.set('port', 9000);

                    // set morgan to log info about our requests for 
                    development use.
                    app.use(morgan('dev'));

                    // initialize body-parser to parse incoming parameters 
                    requests to req.body
                    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

                    // initialize cookie-parser to allow us access the 
                    cookies stored in the browser. 
                    app.use(cookieParser());

                    // initialize express-session to allow us track the 
                    logged-in user across sessions.
                    app.use(session({
                        key: 'user_sid',
                        secret: 'somerandonstuffs',
                        resave: false,
                        saveUninitialized: false,
                        cookie: {
                            expires: 600000
                        }
                    }));


                    // This middleware will check if user's cookie is still 
                    saved in browser and user is not set, then automatically 
                    log the user out.
                    // This usually happens when you stop your express 
                    server after login, your cookie still remains saved in 
                    the browser.
                    app.use((req, res, next) => {
                        if (req.cookies.user_sid && !req.session.user) {
                            res.clearCookie('user_sid');        
                        }
                        next();
                    });


                    // middleware function to check for logged-in users
                    var sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
                        if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
                            res.redirect('/dashboard');
                        } else {
                            next();
                        }    
                    };


                    // route for Home-Page
                    app.get('/', sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
                        res.redirect('/login');
                    });


                    // route for user signup
                    app.route('/signup')
                        .get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
                            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/signup.html');
                        })
                        .post((req, res) => {
                            User.create({
                                username: req.body.username,
                                email: req.body.email,
                                password: req.body.password
                            })
                            .then(user => {
                                req.session.user = user.dataValues;
                                res.redirect('/dashboard');
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                res.redirect('/signup');
                            });
                        });


                    // route for user Login
                    app.route('/login') 
                        .get(sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
                            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
                        })
                        .post((req, res) => {
                            var username = req.body.username,
                                password = req.body.password;


                            User.findOne({ where: { username: username } 
                            }).then(function (user) {
                                if (!!uuser) {
                                    res.redirect('/dashboard`');
                                } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                                    res.redirect('/dashboard');
                                } 
                                else {
                                    req.session.user = user.dataValues;
                                    res.redirect('/dashboard');
                                }
                            });
                        });


                    // route for user's dashboard
                    app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
                        if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
                            res.sendFile(__dirname + 
                    '/public/dashboard.html');
                        } else {
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        }  
                    });

                    app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => {
                        if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
                            res.sendFile(__dirname + 
                   '/public/helloworld.html');
                        } else {
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        }
                    });


                    // route for user logout
                    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
                        if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
                            res.clearCookie('user_sid');
                            res.redirect('/');
                        } else {
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        }
                    });


                    // route for handling 404 requests(unavailable routes)
                    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
                    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
                    });


                    // start the express server
                    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log(`App 
                    started on port ${app.get('port')}`));
```

placeholder

```
                //user.js
                                    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
                            var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


                            //create sequelize instance with local database
                            var sequelize = new 

                Sequelize('mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/authsystem');

                            // setup User model and its fields.
                            var User = sequelize.define('users', {
                                username: {
                                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                                    unique: true,
                                    allowNull: false
                                },
                                email: {
                                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                                    unique: true,
                                    allowNull: false
                                },
                                password: {
                                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                                    allowNull: false
                                }
                            }, {
                                hooks: {
                                beforeCreate: (user) => {
                                    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
                                    user.password = 
                                bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                                }
                                },
                                instanceMethods: {
                                validPassword: function(password) {
                                    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, 
                                this.password);
                                }
                                }    
                            });

                            // create all the defined tables in the 
                             specified database.
                            sequelize.sync()
                                .then(() => console.log('users table has 
                            been successfully created, if one doesn\'t 
                            exist'))
                                .catch(error => console.log('This error 
                           occured', error));

                            // export User model for use in other files.
                            module.exports = User;
```

login.html

```
      //login.html

            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Login Here</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
                </head>
                <body class="container">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Simple Auth-System</h1>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/helloworld">hello world</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>

                    <div class="container row">
                        <div class="jumbotron col-sm-4 pull-center">
                            <form action="/login" method="post">
                                <div>
                                    <label>Username:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="username"/>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label>Password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password"/>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="login()"/>
                                    <script>
                                    function login(){
                                    };
                                    console.log(login);
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                            </form>                  
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

signup.html

```
    //signup.html

            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Login Here</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" 





 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
                 integrity="sha384-
        BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
                  crossorigin="anonymous">
                </head>
                <body class="container">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Simple Auth-System</h1>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other 
                         content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-
                example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                  </li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/helloworld">hello 
                        world</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>

                    <div class="container row">
                        <div class="jumbotron col-sm-4 pull-center">
                            <form action="/signup" method="post">
                                <div>
                                    <label>Username:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="username"/>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label>Email:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email"/>
                                </div>    
                                <div>
                                    <label>Password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password"/>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" 
                type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>                  
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

My gitbash returns the following when I submit a login or new user.
                Attempting to login or signup returns this on my gitbash

```
                    $ node server.js
            sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. 
    Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at 
   http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators 
    node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:236:13
            App started on port 9000
            Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` 
 INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
      `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, UNIQUE 
   `users_username_unique` (`username`), UNIQUE `users_email_unique` 
   (`email`), PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
            Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
            users table has been successfully created, if one doesn't exist
            GET / 302 15.479 ms - 56
            GET /login 304 4.091 ms - -
            GET / 302 1.330 ms - 56
            GET /login 304 2.898 ms - -
            Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, 
     `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE 
      `users`.`username` = 'user' LIMIT 1;
            { id: 25,
            username: 'user',
            email: 'user@user.user',
            password: 
         '$2a$10$X9NEv1MqFffh77BV2lIYLedqYWRUzDM3WlAfzJ9R4Q0oWVDvABqx2',
            createdAt: 2017-12-14T02:08:25.000Z,
            updatedAt: 2017-12-14T02:08:25.000Z }
            ------------------------
            POST /login/verify 302 43.584 ms - 58
            GET /signup 304 1.038 ms - -
```

Can anyone tell me why my registration button is working but not my login button?

Comment: Your clientside login function is blank.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary as far as I can tell, that was just leftover code from me trying to problem solve and not cleaning house fully. If the registration button works as is and the action='/signup' works I can see no reason why the action='/login' button does not.

Comment: Because it's being called by the submit button. By not doing anything it's probably blocking the submit action.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: Attempting to login or signup returns this on my gitbash

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my user.js file. I was not up to date with the latest Sequelize instance.method/model handling.

My existing code was

```
                    // setup User model and its fields.
                    var User = sequelize.define('users', {
                    username: {
                            type: Sequelize.STRING,
                            unique: true,
                            allowNull: false
                    },
                    email: {
                            type: Sequelize.STRING,
                            unique: true,
                            allowNull: false
                    },
                    password: {
                            type: Sequelize.STRING,
                            allowNull: false
                    }
                    }, {
                    hooks: {
                    beforeCreate: (user) => {
                            const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
                            user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                    }
                    },
                    instanceMethods: {
                    validPassword: function(password) {
                            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
                    }
                    }    
                    });
```

Correctly it is

```
        const user = sequelize.define('users', {
            username: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                unique: true,
                allowNull: false
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                unique: true,
                allowNull: false
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            }
        }, {
            hooks: {
                beforeCreate: (user) => {
                    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            }
        })

        user.prototype.validPassword = function (password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
```